# QFileDialog стандартная папка

Tags: c++, qt

Как задать при вызове `QFileDialog` стандартную папку, которая должна показываться?

Comment: `QFileDialog(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR, const QString &caption = QString(), const QString &directory = QString(), const QString &filter = QString())` **`const QString &directory = QString()`** - третий аргумент.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При статическом вызове

```
QFileDialog::QFileDialog(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR, 
    const QString &caption = QString(), 
    const QString &directory = QString(), // <= вот она
    const QString &filter = QString());
```

При создании объекта с помощью функции `setDirectory`

Answer (score 1):

[Пример диалог для выбора картинок](https://github.com/gil9red/InfoAboutQmLang/blob/30a99bc99e610ba1320c3309b784537ebd96a45c/mainwindow.cpp#L37):

```
const QString & dir = QDesktopServices::storageLocation( QDesktopServices::PicturesLocation );
const QString & fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName( this, tr( "Selecting an image" ), dir, filters );
if ( fileName.isEmpty() )
    return;

QPixmap pixmap( fileName );
```